# integral error (first input argument must be function handle.)

Tags: matlab, integral

I want to use an integral over a vector but I will see an error for sys_eff which is " First input argument is not function handle."
I will be glad to have your guide and thanks in advance.
I should mention that all vectors have the same ize as 345600.

```
function [ P_loss,time_eff, sys_eff ] = final( Pmpp, Pl_inv, Pl_bat_inv, Pl_bat_r )

    j=length(Pmpp);
      for t=1:j;
          P_loss(t)= Pl_inv(t) + Pl_bat_inv(t) + Pl_bat_r(t);
          time_eff(t)= P_loss(t)/Pmpp(t);
      end
    sys_eff=integral(time_eff,0,345600);
    end
```

Comment: How do you interpret the error message? It says *First input argument is not function handle.* - could it be that you are passing a variable and not a function?

Comment: Read the documentation for [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html), it is for integrating functions. [`trapz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) is a numeric integration and likely what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you excaza :) with this function it works properly.
Thanks for comment Schorsch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from the error message, the first input you provided to the function `integral` (i.e. `time_eff`) is not a function handle, but a vector.
If you want to make a numeric integral of the function use the function `trapz`

```
sys_eff=trapz(t,time_eff)
```

if t is your integration variable.